# React Context Provider that knows whether any components are mounted that use this context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a context provider which maintains a websocket connection to the server and exposes some state that the server can update, and is trivial for components to consume. This much works fine.

However, the websocket code connects whenever the *provider* is mounted - which in my case is basically always. But about half the time there aren't actually any components rendered that consume this context.

Is it possible for my provider to know when there are no components mounted that consume its context, so that it could connect/disconnect only as required?

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, how about making the components call the context on mount and unmount:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // This will run when the component is mounted
  registerIncontext("componentId");
  return () => {
    // This will run when the component is unmounted
    unregisterIncontext("componentId");
  };
}, []);
```

You will have to expose a way to register and unregister in the context.

Comment: Yes, I suppose this would work.